# jQuery условие

Tags: jquery

Добрый вечер

Как в jQuery сделать условие такого вида?

```
if(('#element').show()){  
    ('#element').hide();
}
```

Елемент до этого может появляться методом show("slide",...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('#element').is(':visible'))
   ('#element').hide();
```

Comment: Спасибо, будем знать :)